# Generic function in Vala

Tags: function, generics, vala

I wrote a maximum() generic function in Vala.
However, it does not compile.
Here it is:

```
T maximum<T>(T a, T b) {
    return a > b ? a : b;
}

void main() {
    stdout.printf("%d\n", maximum(10, 2));
}
```

I got the following error:

```
generics.vala:2.12-2.16: error: Relational operation not supported for types `T' and `T'
```

Do you know how I can fix this function to be able to compile it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generic direct comparison and various other operations aren't supported by current Vala. You may want to use and implement Gee.Comparable interface to use a compare_to() method instead.